# Are there no existing Java classes for Google place autocomplete and maps directions?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm thinking of writing an app that make use of the places autocomplete and maps directions, but find it really odd that the Google docs for its only provides a rest api.

Am I having a brain fact, or are there truly no Places Autocomplete text fields provided via the SDK? and similarly for maps directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no brain fart. that's just how it is.

there is, however, [a github](https://github.com/gmarz/android-google-places) project that's supposed to handle the rest api calls for you. haven't used it, so not sure if its any good.

Answer (score 0):

The [Web Services APIs](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/) can now be used in Java with this native client library: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

No Places API unfortunately but the Directions API is in there.